# How to check json format in SQL?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, string, where-clause

I have a table with a column of type Nvarchar where json is stored. But the format of some of its columns is wrong. So I get an error when I parse them all.

I want my query to ignore lines that have errors.

```
SELECT *
FROM RequestLogs
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(body) WITH(
    user varchar(60) '$.user',
    pass varchar(60) '$.pass'
    ) as a
```

It gives this error when I run on all lines:

> JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '.' is found
> at position 0.

, but it executes correctly on the `top 10`.

Comment: Can you post the wrong data?

Comment: Because when you run with `TOP 10` the 10 arbitrary, or 10 rows first as defined by the `ORDER BY` have valid JSON, where as when looking at the entire table *at least* one row does not. Try `SELECT [body] FROM dbo.RequsetLogs WHERE ISJSON([body]) = 0;` and fix the bad data.

Comment: @Zhorov I can not find problematic data. If I knew, I would delete it. Is there a way to find them?

Comment: @MohammadNazari `ISJSON()` will help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you could use `ISJSON()`to check the validity of `body` before passing it to `OPENJSON()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM RequestLogs WHERE ISJSON(body) = 1) as r
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(body) WITH(
    user varchar(60) '$.user',
    pass varchar(60) '$.pass'
) as a
```

This filters out rows whose content is invalid. If you want to retain them, and return a `null` result instead, then:

```
SELECT r.*, a.*
FROM RequestLogs r
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CASE WHEN WHERE ISJSON(r.body) = 1 THEN r.body END)) as x(body)
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(x.body) WITH(
    user varchar(60) '$.user',
    pass varchar(60) '$.pass'
) as a
```

And, of course, you can identify the offending rows like so:

```
SELECT body
FROM RequestLogs 
WHERE ISJSON(body) = 0
```